# SharePoint app not writing to list (Javascript)

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I am trying to create an app which posts information to a SharePoint List.

```
function createListItem() {

    try {
        var userName = document.getElementById("name").value;

        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('LeaveRequest');
        var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
        this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

        oListItem.set_item('Title', userName);

        oListItem.update();
        clientContext.load(oListItem);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    }
    catch (err)
    {
        alert(err.message);
    }
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

    alert('Item created Successfully! ' + oListItem.get_id());

}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

When I click the submit button on the form, I am getting an alert to say the item has been added and also an id for the item in the list. However when I check the list the item is not there.

Comment: Your code works within my SharePoint solution. Please try again, copy the new ID and go the _LeaveRequest_ list page, open any item and change the ID parameter value in the URL with your previously created item ID.

Comment: Hi @Salah ive tried that too, it just results in "page not found"

Comment: Probably that's permissions things.. Try to run the code using site collection admin account and check that an item was created.

Comment: May be you create list item in not expected by you list ? What relative path to your form with script ? What relative path to list where you try to find newly created item ? Or may be second thing - how you check that item is created in list ? What you do ? May be you open list view where some custom filter options applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, you created list item in add-in web(URL like https://tenant-d3bbc7b89c212c.sharepoint.com/sites/Developer/addinName/) not host web(https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/developer).

So, confirm the list item in add-in web (https://tenant-d3bbc7b89c212c.sharepoint.com/sites/Developer/addinName/lists/LeaveRequest)

Check [official guideline](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/work-with-host-web-data-from-javascript-in-the-add-in-web) to create list item in host web.